# polynomial regression in lm (2 Methods)

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying to do a polynomial regression in R using `lm`, I have

```
Time=c(1980:2016)
y= rnorm(length(Time))
```

I used :

```
reg=lm(y~poly(Time,2))
round(reg$coefficients,3)
```

which gives :

```
 (Intercept) poly(Time, 2)1 poly(Time, 2)2 
        -0.110         -1.298          0.172
```

And :

```
Time2=Time^2
reg2=lm(y~Time+Time2)
round(reg2$coefficients,3)
```

It gives

```
(Intercept)        Time       Time2 
   1146.590      -1.128       0.000
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: "Where is the problem?" - I'm inclined to ask you the same thing. You've fit two different models and gotten two different answers. Where is the problem?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Time2=Tme^2

Comment: @joran I used 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-polynomial-regression-in-r/

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, thanks for pointing out the dupe.  At least my answer adds a little (I think) to existing answers ...

Answer (score 5):

By default `poly()` uses an *orthogonal polynomial* representation, which is more numerically stable. You can use `raw=TRUE` if you want to match the naive representation.

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(Time=c(1980:2016),
                y=rnorm(2016-1980+1))
(c1 <- coef(lm(y~Time+I(Time^2),dd)))
##   (Intercept)          Time     I(Time^2) 
##  6.684138e+03 -6.686392e+00  1.672101e-03 
(c2 <- coef(lm(y~poly(Time,2),dd)))
##    (Intercept) poly(Time, 2)1 poly(Time, 2)2 
##    -0.04713527    -0.30359154     1.03594479 
c3 <- coef(lm(y~poly(Time,2,raw=TRUE),dd))
all.equal(unname(c1),unname(c3))  ## TRUE
```

You'll notice among other things that the intercept and slope given by the raw polynomials refer to the expected values *at Time=0*, which if you're using Time in CE (Common Era=AD) years is a little ridiculous.

If you want both interpretability and numerical stability you can get a reasonable compromise by centering your time variable (setting time to zero at the beginning of your observation period is also reasonable).

```
dd$cTime <- dd$Time-mean(dd$Time)
c4 <- coef(lm(y~poly(cTime,2,raw=TRUE),dd))
unname(c4)
## [1] -0.237754839 -0.004674513  0.001672101
```